# Saving some user information to a different table in laravel

Tags: laravel, orm

I have tried to add to do some modification to Registration Controller. I want to add some users record to a different table but I can't get it right. I'm able to capture all the field using dd($data). But I am unable to save the data to the userRecord Table.

In Registration controller

```
 protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
            'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8', 'confirmed'],
            'phoneno' => ['required', 'string', 'min:11']
            'areas' => ['required', 'string']

        ]);
    }    

protected function create(array $data)
    {
        $user = User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
        ]);
        $user->attachRole('user');
        $userRecord = new UserRecords();
        $userRecord->phoneno = $data->phoneno;//additional fields
        $userRecord->email= $data->email;
        $userRecord->areas= $data->areas;//additional fields
        $userRecord->save();
     }
```

My model

```
<?php
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class userRecords extends Model
{
     protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email','phoneno','location',
    ];
}
```

My View

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container mt-4">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header bg-info text-white">{{ __('Register') }}</div>

                <div class="card-body">
                    <form method="POST" action="{{ route('register') }}">
                        @csrf

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="name" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Name') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="name" type="text" class="form-control @error('name') is-invalid @enderror" name="name" value="{{ old('name') }}" required autocomplete="name" autofocus>

                                @error('name')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>
                          <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="name" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Phone Number') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="phoneno" type="text" class="form-control">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="email" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('E-Mail Address') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control @error('email') is-invalid @enderror" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" required autocomplete="email">

                                @error('email')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>
                           <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="name" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Your Location') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                            <select name="areas" id="areas" class="form-control">
                          @foreach($areas as $item)
                            <option value="{{ $item->area }}">{{ $item->area}}</option>
                          @endforeach
                        </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="password" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Password') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control @error('password') is-invalid @enderror" name="password" required autocomplete="new-password">

                                @error('password')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="password-confirm" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Confirm Password') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="password-confirm" type="password" class="form-control" name="password_confirmation" required autocomplete="new-password">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row mb-0">
                            <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-4">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                    {{ __('Register') }}
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

Comment: Did you get any error?

Comment: @ThânLƯƠNG  yap Trying to get property 'phoneno' of non-object

Comment: I see that `$data` is an array. But, you get values as object.

Comment: You should change `$data->phoneno` into `$data['phoneno']`, `$data->email` into `$data['email']`, `$data->areas` into `$data['areas']`. Does it work?

Comment: @ThânLƯƠNG Thanks now the data is saved but I get an error in the view page Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard::login() must implement interface Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable

Comment: Could you please share model `User`?

Comment: @ThânLƯƠNG Thanks alot I have added use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable in both classes and now it is okay. But not sure whether it will throw another error since I wanted to avoid using Auth tables

Answer (score 0):

1. 

> Trying to get property 'phoneno' of non-object

`$data` is an array. But, you get values of `$data` as object. You should change 
`$data->phoneno` into `$data['phoneno']`,
 `$data->email` into `$data['email']`,
 `$data->areas` into `$data['areas']`.

2.

> But not sure whether it will throw another error since I wanted to avoid using Auth tables

I think you can open another topic to clarify this.

Answer (score 0):

A few things you need to set correct

- Your model is `userRecords` so when newing up an instance `new userRecords`
- $data is an array so access properties/elements with array syntax `$data['email']`
- You need to return `$user` from create method

```php
protected function create(array $data)
{
    $user = User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
    ]);

    $user->attachRole('user');

    $userRecord = new userRecords();
    $userRecord->phoneno = $data['phoneno'];//additional fields
    $userRecord->email= $data['email'];
    $userRecord->areas= $data['areas'];//additional fields
    $userRecord->save();

    return $user;
}
```